# Run Debian XFCE without a monitor

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, xfce, headless

I want to run a program via ssh on a debian xfce pc, the program generates a file, my problem is that this program needs a screen to open, it will NOT work in terminal mode.

I want xfce to boot without a monitor(screen), i tried changing in xorg.conf.d, but no luck (maybe I used conf for another distribution).

I do not want hardware fix(resistors..).

Cheers..

Edit:
@eyoung100 Thanks a bunch, the dummy thing with the conf given in that post did it!!
Write as an answer so I mark it as answer.

@terdon I didn't want to display, but freeglut programs don't run without a DISPLAY.

@Adrián Arroyo Calle Thanks, eyoung100 solution worked for me, but I think XVFB was a solution also.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really can't understand what you're asking. Where would you want the program displayed? On your local screen right? How are you connecting to the Debian box? Are you using `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y`? What did you change in `xorg.conf.d`? Is there a screen attached to the machine? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Does [this post help](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1832456)?

Answer (score 0):

Try Xvfb, is a X11 server that runs without screen and works with a framebuffer. All X11 programs and utilities work with Xvfb.